# How is this higher order function working?

Tags: javascript, filter, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

I was reading through a guide on react and one of the examples has confused me a little, here is a section of it:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

function doFilter(query) {
  return function (user) {
    return query === user.name;
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  ...

  render() {
    const users = [
      { name: 'Robin' },
      { name: 'Markus' },
    ];

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {users
            .filter(doFilter(this.state.query))
            .map(user => <li>{user.name}</li>)
```

I don't understand the filter - I know a filter takes a callback which should return either true or false, in this case the doFilter function returns another function, I'm not sure how or when this returned function is being invoked, since filter has already invoked the doFilter function.

If someone can please break down the steps of whats happening it would help.

Comment: Filter doesn't invoke doFilter; doFilter is invoked **then** the function it returns is invoked by filter. You could extract that returned function to a variable, that might clarify the flow. That's what higher order function *means*, a function that returns (and/or accepts) a function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe is correct. It is as if you had these two lines. `const filterPredicate = doFilter(this.state.query);`  `users.filter(filterPredicate).map....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following:

```
users.filter(doFilter(this.state.query))
```

... the first thing that happens is the evaluation of `this.state.query` and then the call to `doFilter` passing it that value.

This returns a function that looks like this:

```
function (user) {
  return query === user.name;
}
```

The value of `query` is bound to the value that was passed to `doFilter`.

Then, `users.filter` is called with this function as argument. Note that at this stage, `doFilter` is no longer playing any role. It is the anonymous function that performs the filtering, returning a boolean for each `user` it gets called with.

Comment: Thanks, so there is a closure between the doFilter which passes query in to its return function?

Comment: Indeed the variable `query` refers to the argument passed to `doFilter`, which provides the closure for that variable.